# How to calculate power necessary generated from wind turbine to run a motor

Tags: renewable-energy

I was making a small/cheap wind turbine, and I am stuck on how to calculate the power needed (speed of wind) to run a brushed motor (since I figured that would be the easiest to run with rotor blades of the turbine made out of plastic). The dimensions of the length of one rotor blade is 6 inches

Comment: In principle this is a very good question, but it seems like we will need quite a bit more information. Like, angle of the rotor with respect to the wind, weight of the rotor, torque required to move the brushes, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power generated by wind turbine goes approximately like

$P={1\over 2}C_p\rho A v^3$

Where $\rho$ is the density of air, $A=\pi r^2$ is the area swept by the blades, $v$ is the velocity of the wind and $C_p$ is a power conversion factor that is around 0.3-0.4 for the best wind turbine designs and will probably be on the order of 0.1 for your rotor. Putting it together we get roughly the following numerical expression for your design:

$P\approx 0.5\times 0.1\times 1.225{kg\over m^3} \times 3.14 \times ({6\over 39.37} m)^2 \times v^3 \approx 0.0045 {kg\over m} v^3 = 0.0045 {kg \over m}{m^3\over s^3} ({v\over m/s})^3\approx 0.0045W ({v\over m/s})^3$

At 1m/s (light air) your wind generator may produce approx. 4.5mW, at 10m/s (strong breeze) it may go up to 1000 times that much, i.e. theoretically 4.5W. And there you can see why wind turbines have to be so large to produce significant amounts of wind power and why, even more so, strong winds are essential.

Comment: how do you calculate voltage from this?

Comment: The voltage will depend on your generator and the rpm at which the blades are turning. Wind turbines have gearboxes to adjust that ration for the max. power efficiency. Since I don't have the details about your generator (dc motor), I couldn't tell. You should measure it with a voltmeter.

Comment: okay I thought there was a way to calculate voltage also theoretically using the power equation you provided above. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a theoretical way to calculate voltage that a wind turbine will produce based on given speed of wind?

Comment: Only if you know the characteristics of the generator and a few other things. Importantly, though, voltage is not important. Voltage can be changed without losing much power. What's important is always the power. Whether you generate 4.5V and 1A or 9V and 0.5A, that's all the same, a little bit of electronics can convert that into anything you like. The hard part is to generate the power in the first place.

Comment: how do you calculate Cp?

Comment: @user510: With great effort. One would have to do aerodynamic simulations of the design similar to what is being done to optimize planes.  One can prove that $C_p$ has to be below 0.59, i.e. no wind turbine can convert all of the energy in the wind. This is known as Betz's law and intuitively this is  somewhat obvious, since one can't just stop the airflow, the air after the turbine still has to be moving with some velocity, otherwise new air couldn't flow across the blades. That's the theoretical limit... practical turbines can achieve about 75-80% of it.

Comment: ok I tried to use equation of Cp and tip speed ratio, but that gave me a negative value for Cp which would mean I have negative power. My tip speed ratio was 2.2. However, I could not figure out what the pitch angle was, which is what I think is the reason why I am getting a negative value (I assumed that my pitch angle was 0). Can you explain me what a pitch angle is?